# Arrangements of crew in two sides of a boat - permutations and combinations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> A boat crew consist of 8 men, 3 of whom can row only on one side and 2
>   only on the other. The number of ways in which the crew can be
>   arranged is

This is a problem my math teacher has given to us as an exercise. Answer given is $1728$. We were asked to derive the answer. I could understand how the answer is $1728$. The following explanation is taken from [beatthegmat.com](http://www.beatthegmat.com/p-c-1-t17309.html)

> You can arrange each side using 4! But you have 3 guys that are
>   flexible and can sub anywhere. So 3*4!*4!

[careerbless.com](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=2695) also derives the answer $1728$. But, they also explains answer can be $8$ if the question is interpreted as follows

> (1) there is no restriction on how many people can sit on a side.
>
> (2) arrangements of the persons within a particular side does not
>   matter.

So, I ended up with the following doubts

> (1) Whether the most obvious answer is $8$ or $1728$ for this question?
>
> (2) If assumptions are made as careerbless team did, then, I can come
>   up with my own assumptions as well. For example, If I read this
>   question as
>
> > (1) there is no restriction on how many people can sit on a side.
> >
> > (2) arrangements of the persons within a particular side are important
>
> In this case, I may get another answer as 8×4!×4!

As a student, It is important for me to clear this as all problems can also be read in similar manner. Please help to clear my doubts as it is impossible for me to get such a support in classroom.

Comment: In reality, four people sit on each side.  Otherwise, the boat would tend to tip over.  I would interpret the question to mean that four people sit on each side of the boat.  The word arrangements suggests that the positions of the people on each side matters.

Comment: @Kiran no guideline can help us to manage a question which is not well defined, in maths and ..daily life.

Comment: I suppose the best you can do is to explicitly state all assumptions when you answer.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig, I got your point. But, normally for problems dealing with arrangement of balls inside boxes, the order of the balls inside a box are not important (unless explicitly stated). Therefore, we cannot make a general assumption just because of the word arrangements, isn't it?

Comment: That is true.  However, in this case, we are talking about arrangements of people.  People are distinguishable, while balls of the same color may not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see why you're unsure how to proceed.  There are unstated assumptions in the question.  In an ideal world, you'd know exactly what's being asked, but this isn't an ideal world.

I can tell you why I'd *suspect* that there need to be four rowers on each side, though:

- For most situations it's impractical to have more rowers on one side than the other.  The shorthanded side would get more tired, or just wouldn't be able to match the other side, and the ship would go around in circles.
- The problem becomes more involved if you don't restrict the number of rowers to four on each side.  One side (the side with the three "inflexible" rowers) can have anywhere from three to six rowers on it if you don't restrict that.  This means more cases to consider.  In an exam setting, given the other problems you'd have to solve, would this take up too much time?

Comment: ok, got the point, thanks a lot for the help